# How does std::bind Results in calling the Copy Constructor Several Times

Tags: c++, c++11, bind, auto, stdbind

I have been trying to understand how std::bind works. So working up with different examples. Below is the sample program whose output i am unable to understand.

**VERSION 1**

```
class NAME
{
  public:
    void f()
    {
        std::cout<<"f"<<std::endl;
    }
    NAME()
    {
        std::cout<<"default constructor"<<std::endl;
    }
    NAME(const NAME&)
    {
        std::cout<<"copy constructor"<<std::endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl; 
   NAME n;
   std::function<void ()> callable = std::bind(&NAME::f, n);
   
   
   return 0;
}
```

The output of the above version 1 is as follows:

```
Hello World
default constructor
copy constructor
copy constructor
```

I know that the argument passed will be copied, so the copy constructor should be called only one time but in the output above the copy constructor is called twice. Why/how is this happening? Is it because the new callable that is created using std::bind will be used to initialize another callable using std::function on the lhs?

**VERSION 2**

```
int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl; 
   NAME n;
   std::function<void ()> callable = std::move(std::bind(&NAME::f, n));
   return 0;
}
```

The output of VERSION 2 is as follows:

```
Hello World
default constructor
copy constructor
copy constructor
copy constructor
```

In the output above(for version 2) when i use std::move, why/how is the copy constructor called thrice?

**VERSION 3**

```
int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl; 
   NAME n;
   auto callable = std::bind(&NAME::f, n);
   return 0;
}
```

The output of version 3 is as follows:

```
Hello World
default constructor
copy constructor
```

In this case(version 3) why/how is the copy constructor called only once?

**VERSION 4**

```
int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl; 
   NAME n;
   auto callable = std::move(std::bind(&NAME::f, n));
   return 0;
}
```

The output of version 4 is as follows:

```
Hello World
default constructor
copy constructor
copy constructor
```

What happens in this case(version 4) when we use `auto` and `std::move()`, why/how is the copy constructor called twice.

PS: The program is executed on an online compiler: [Online compiler Used](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php)

**Edit:** Upon reading the comments i have a further question/doubt:

**Question 1**

If i use `auto callable_1 = std::bind(&NAME::f, n);` and `std::function<void ()> callable_2 = std::bind(&NAME::f, n);` then are the types of `callable_1` and `callable_2` different? If yes, then what is the type deduced by `auto` for `callable_1`? Or is it that the type deduced by `auto` for `callable_1` will be an unnamed class object just like for a `lambda`.

**Question 2**

I have one further question: As i did in my case, if i pass `n` instead of `&n` in `std::bind` then is the code legal? For example, if i write `std::function<void ()> callable_1 = std::bind(&NAME::f, n);` and `auto callable_2 = std::bind(&NAME::f, n);` then are both of these illegal? What if i passed `ref(n)` instead of `n` in both of these cases, then will they be illegal or legal?

**Question 3**

Are the statements `auto callable = [&n]{n.f()};` and `auto callable = std::bind(&NAME::f, cref(n));` equivalent(in functionality) and maybe in some other ways and is there any reason(advantage) to pick one over another apart from coding style?

**Question 4**

What if i write `auto callable = std::bind(&NAME::f, 1_); callable(n); callable(std::ref(n));`. Is the statement `callable(n)` illegal? And what about the statement `callable(std::ref(n));`.

Comment: All the questions here seem to revolve around two topics.  1. - the overhead of `std::function`.  2. - the pessimizations possible from `std::move`.

Comment: On a side note: `NAME::f()` expects a `NAME*` pointer to an object for its `this` parameter, not a `NAME` object itself. So the call to `std::bind()` should be using `&n` instead. Then no copies of `n` would be made at all: `std::bind(&NAME::f, &n)`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes i already know that if we use `&n` instead of `n` in `std::bind` then no copy will be made at all. In this case my question is that if we pass `n` instead of `&n` just like i did, then is the code legal ?

Comment: @JasonLiam I want to say no, `f()` would not be passed a proper `this` value if `n` is copied. But that doesn't seem to be the case (unless this is compiler-dependent behavior): https://ideone.com/MxN29P. On the other hand, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind says: "*As described in `Callable`, when invoking a pointer to non-static member function or pointer to non-static data member, **the first argument has to be a reference or pointer** (including, possibly, smart pointer such as `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`) to an object whose member will be accessed.*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, according to the [rules for move constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor), no implicit move constructor is defined for the class `NAME`. Further, from the Notes [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor):

> If only the copy constructor is provided, all argument categories
> select it (as long as it takes a reference to const, since rvalues can
> bind to const references), which makes copying the fallback for
> moving, when moving is unavailable.

So, whenever you use `std::move` you are eventually calling a copy constructor. This explains why Version 4 (respectively, Version 2) has an additional call to the copy constructor compared to Version 3 (respectively, Version 1).

Let us see the remaining copy constructors.

As you correctly pointed out, a copy constructor is called from passing second argument of `std::bind`. This account for the first call in all versions.

When you declare

```
 std::function<void ()> callable = std::bind(&NAME::f, n);
```

you are calling the constructor of `std::function`, passing a single parameter `std::bind(&NAME::f, n)` which is then, again, copied. This account for the second call of copy constructor of version 1, and the third call in version 2. Notice that [mandatory copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) does not apply here, because you are not passing a `std::function` object.

Finally, when you use

```
auto callable = std::bind(...)
```

you are declaring a variable which is of an unnamed type, and contains the result of the call to `std::bind`.
No copy is involved in the declaration. This is why version 3 has one less call to copy constructor compared to version 1.

**Answers to the additional questions**

1.

The types of `callable_1` and `callable_2` are different. `callable_2` is a `std::function` object, while `callable_1` is an [unspecified type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), the result of `std::bind`. Also, it is not a [lamda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). To see this, you can run a code like

```
   auto callable_1 = std::bind(&NAME::f, n);
   std::function<void ()> callable_2 = std::bind(&NAME::f, n);
   // a generic lambda
   auto callable_3 = [&]() { n.f(); };
   std::cout << std::boolalpha;
   std::cout << std::is_bind_expression<decltype(callable_1)>::value << std::endl;
   std::cout << std::is_bind_expression<decltype(callable_2)>::value << std::endl;
   std::cout << std::is_bind_expression<decltype(callable_3)>::value << std::endl;
```

See it [live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b5f83bdf4785803).

2.

As noted by @RemyLebeau, a strict interpretation of the Notes in the [reference of `std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

> As described in Callable, when invoking a pointer to non-static member
> function or pointer to non-static data member, the first argument has
> to be a reference or pointer (including, possibly, smart pointer such
> as std::shared_ptr and std::unique_ptr) to an object whose member will
> be accessed.

would suggest that the code must be called with `&n` and a call with `n` would be illegal.

However, a call to `operator()` results in a `std::invoke`. From the [reference of `std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) we read (little reformatting by me):

> If f is a pointer to member function of class T:
>
> a) If std::is_base_of<T, std::decay_t<decltype(t1)>>::value is true, then INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN) is equivalent to (t1.*f)(t2,
> ..., tN)
>
> b) If std::decay_t<decltype(t1)> is a specialization of
> std::reference_wrapper, then INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN) is equivalent
> to (t1.get().*f)(t2, ..., tN)
>
> c) If t1 does not satisfy the previous
> items, then INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN) is equivalent to ((*t1).*f)(t2,
> ..., tN).

According to this, calling `std::bind` with `n` (case a)) or `&n` (case c)) should be equivalent (apart from the additional copy if you use `n`), because `std::decay_t<decltype(n)>` gives `NAME` and `std::is_base_of<NAME, NAME>::value` is `true` (see [reference for `std::is_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of)).
Passing `ref(n)` corresponds to the case b), so again it should be correct and equivalent to the other cases (apart from the copies discussed above).

3.

Notice that `cref` gives you a reference wrapper to `const NAME&`. So you will not be able to call `callable` because `NAME::f` is not a const member function. In fact, if you add a `callable();` the code [does not compile](https://godbolt.org/z/b98Mx9xd1).

Apart from this issue, if you use instead `std::ref` or if `NAME::f` is `const`, I do not see a fundamental difference between `auto callable = [&n]{n.f()};` and `auto callable = std::bind(&NAME::f, ref(n));`. With these regards, notice [that](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

> The arguments to bind are copied or moved, and are never passed by
> reference unless wrapped in std::ref or std::cref.

Personally, I find the lambda syntax much clearer.

4.

From the [reference for `std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), under `operator()` we read

> If the stored argument arg is of type T, for which
> std::is_placeholder::value != 0 (meaning, a placeholder such as
> std::placeholders::_1, _2, _3, ... was used as the argument to the
> initial call to bind), then the argument indicated by the placeholder
> (u1 for _1, u2 for _2, etc) is passed to the invokable object: the
> argument vn in the std::invoke call above is std::forward(uj) and
> the corresponding type Vn in the same call is Uj&&.

Thus, the effect of using placeholders falls back to the cases of question 1. The code indeed [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/68Mjzv57f) with different compilers.

Comment: I have one further question: As i did in my case, if i pass `n` instead of `&n` in `std::bind` then is the code legal? For example, if i write `std::function<void ()> callable_1 = std::bind(&NAME::f, n);` and `auto callable_2 = std::bind(&NAME::f, n);` then are both of these illegal? What if i passed  `ref(n)` instead of `n` in both of these cases, then will they be illegal or legal?

Comment: I have edited my question(in the Edit part), can you also answer those remaining questions.

Answer (score 2):

```
// default constructor will be called
NAME n; 

// bind makes a copy of n into an internal struct, copy constructor of n is called.
auto fn = std::bind(&NAME::f, n); 

// assignment operator makes a copy of members of fn to members of std::function. 
// This is also a copy constructor call of NAME
std::function<void ()> callable = fn;
```

Note:
Instead of bind, you can also use lambda's

```
std::function<void ()> callable([&n]{n.f()});
```

Comment: A valid observation, but I don't think this is an _answer_ to the questions asked.  This perhaps should be a comment.

Comment: Does this mean if i use `auto callable_1 = std::bind(&NAME::f, n);` and `std::function<void ()> callable_2 = std::bind(&NAME::f, n);` then the types of `callable_1` and `callable_2` are different? If yes, then what is the type deduced by auto for `callable_1`? Or is it that the type deduced by auto for `callable_1` will be an unnamed class object just like for a lambda?

Comment: callable_1 will have the same signature as callable2, std::function<void()> it will be different instances.
the lambda will be unnamed (it will have some strange generated type), but you can assign it to a std::function if the signature of the lambda matches that of the std::function.
You can let the compiler deduce a std::function type from a lambda but its somewhat advanced (I'll add another answer for that)

Comment: @JasonLiam `std::bind()` does not return a `std::function`, but rather an unspecified implementation-defined type that is assignable to a `std::function`. So yes, `callable_1` and `callable_2` will have different types

Answer (score 1):

```
#pragma once

namespace details
{
    template<typename T>
    struct memfun_type
    {
        using type = void;
    };

    template<typename RetvalType, typename ClassType, typename... Args>
    struct memfun_type<RetvalType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const>
    {
        using type = typename std::function<RetvalType(Args...)>;
    };

} // details

template<typename Fn>
typename details::memfun_type<decltype(&Fn::operator())>::type 
make_std_function(Fn const& fn)
{
    return fn;
}
```

And now you can make std::function<RetvalType(Args...)> from lambdas like this

```
auto std_fn = make_std_function([](int n){return 2*n;});
int answer = std_fn(2);
```

Comment: I have added some more questions in the "Edit" part of my question. Can you answer them too. You can just append them to your previous answer.

Comment: I don't have enough experience to make statements on std::bind created functions.
I switched to lambdas long ago. I do have one warning on using ref's though. You must be sure the referenced objects are still alive when the constructed function (doesn't matter if its created by bind or lambda). So passing local (stack) variables can be tricky (and things get even more interesting when you pass lambdas or std::functions with refs to other threads)