# Why is std::function trying to call the copy constructor here?

Tags: c++, std-function

```
#include <functional>
struct MyFoo
{
    MyFoo() {}
    MyFoo(const MyFoo&) = delete;
    MyFoo(MyFoo&&) = default;
    MyFoo& operator=(const MyFoo&) = delete;
    MyFoo& operator=(MyFoo&&) = default;
    void operator()(int) {

    }
};

int main(void)
{
    std::function<void(int)> foo{MyFoo()}; 
}

Error   C2280   'MyFoo::MyFoo(const MyFoo &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

MyFoo is an r-value. When it comes time to take a copy of it, std::function shouldn't copy it but move it.

Comment: [Rationale behind making std::function require copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59967794/rationale-behind-making-stdfunction-require-copy-constructor) and [How does std::bind Results in calling the Copy Constructor Several Times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68911076/how-does-stdbind-results-in-calling-the-copy-constructor-several-times)

Comment: Short answer: `std::function` requires the callable to be copy-constructible because it itself provides a copy constructor. This need to compile, since `std::function` is not a template. There are some alternatives, but AFAIK not in `std` yet; see, e.g., https://github.com/Naios/function2. A relevant proposal: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0288r7.html.

Comment: there is [std::move_only_function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/move_only_function/move_only_function) in C++23 which should be used for move-only types ... exactly what you are trying to do. if you don't have access to C++23 you can use a library or write your own if you understand type-erasure.

Answer (score 3):

`std::function` *always* requires the provided callable type to be copy-constructible. What member functions you use is irrelevant.

As for the implementation reason: In order for type erasure as used by `std::function` to work, all possibly usable functionality must be instantiated for the given callable type at the point of construction, since use sites can't know that this specific callable type may be used in a `std::function` instance. And `std::function` permits copying and so this is relevant.

Comment: I have no idea what you've just said "all possibly usable functionality must be instantiated for the given callable type at the point of construction,all possibly usable functionality must be instantiated for the given callable type at the point of construction,", can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @Zebrafish consider a `std::vector<T>` where `T` is not default constructible. You cannot `resize()` but you can construct such vector (because not all methods are immediately instantiated)

Comment: Does this mean that the copy constructor of whatever callable you pass to std::function constructor is copied? Likewise assigning a new callable to it it makes a copy of it? Boo, that sucks.

Comment: @Zebrafish No, no copy constructor is used in your example. It will be moved. But suppose someone in another translation unit tries to copy your `foo`. In that translation unit there is no knowledge that a `std::function` might store a `MyFoo`. So it is impossible to instantiate the copy constructor there. But then, what function should be called by the copy construction in that translation unit if it stores a `MyFoo`? The only solution is to instantiate in the translation unit where the `MyFoo` is stored into a `std::function` object.

Comment: @Zebrafish no thats not what this answer says. `std::funciton` has move assignment (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator%3D). But a user might make a copy and you cannot en/disable copy on the fly depending on what callable is assigned.

Comment: @Zebrafish If you want a more detailed explanation look up an explanation of type erasure in C++.

Comment: @user17732522 What is it that makes it instantiate the copy constructor if it's not being called. So I moved it, which doesn't need the copy constructor, but you're saying that the code to copy it needs to be instantiated in that translation unit, what is it that makes that happen? The way that you get the compiler to instantiate something is by using it, what does the code do to do that?

Comment: @Zebrafish `std::function` is just a struct of pointers to the copy constructor and call operator and destructor (actually a wrapper around them), to construct a `std::function` you have to fill those pointers in the constructor, once it is constructed you can pass this struct across translation units boundaries without knowing what the stored object is, this is type-erasure in a nutshell, the compiler cannot instantiate `std::function` without knowing those 3 operations because it doesn't know what other translation units can do.

Comment: @Zebrafish "what is it that ..." gcc is a bit more talkative, they placed a `static_assert` that uses a trait to check the constraint https://godbolt.org/z/qq5458nz1. mscv can do it differently though

Comment: @Zebrafish note that its a `static_assert` (perhaps inside the constructor). If the constructor you are calling would not move, but make a copy, that assert wasnt needed

Comment: @Zebrafish As mentioned in a comment above: The instantiation is triggered by taking the address of the function that should be instantiated or by the function being a virtual function. In the latter case the instantiation decision is up to the compiler, but the compiler has to guarantee that the instantiation happens somewhere if the virtual function might be called, so it will be in the unit that creates an object of the type.